# brownian translation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, brownian-motion

I have a bit of struggle with understanding what it means to have the same law as a brownian. For instance, how can i prove that $$\sup_{t\in[k-1,k]} |W_t - W_{k-1}| \stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{=} \sup_{t\in[0,1[} |W_t| $$
where $k \in \mathbb{Z}.$ 
My attempt at a proof is the following: 
since $W_t - W_{k-1} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t-(k-1))$, and $W_{t-(k-1)} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t-(k-1))$ : 
$$W_t - W_{k-1} \stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{=} W_{t-(k-1)}$$ hence the equality above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No!  You need much more than just $W_t-W_{k-1}\sim N(0,t-k+1)$.

You want to show that $W_{t+k}-W_k$ is another Wiener process, i.e., you want to show

- it is almost surely $=0$ at $t=0$,
- independent Gaussian increments, and
- continuous paths with probability 1

These follows from $W_t$ being a Wiener process (why?).

Comment: Independent gaussian increments follows from the fact that : $W_t$ is a gaussian process and it suffices to show that the covariances are equal to $0$. Continuous paths follows from the continuity of the paths of $W_t$, and $=0$ is trivial at $t=0$. Therefore $(W_{t+(k-1)} - W_{k-1})_{t \in [0,1]}$ has same law as $(W_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ ?